# how to close/stop the music which is playing in background in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i stop the music/song which is currently playing in background from my app?

When user clicks the stop button in my app it should close/stop the music.

How to implement this functionality.

Thanks...

Comment: It depends on how you implemented your Background music. If it is BackgroundAudioPlayer then `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop()` (or Pause()) should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But my intention is to stop the music which is playing in background. Music is not from my app.

Comment: There is one instance of BAP on the phone and you can AFAIK stop it as I've mentioned. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to detect if an audio stream is playing: `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.State`

But you can't stop it if it's wasn't launched from you app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have seen "Quick settings" app, which has the button to close the music. When I click the button its closing any music.

Comment: There's no direct method. Of course you can find a workaround, such as quering an audio playback with a "mute sound" so that the current stream is closed and it play a file from your app instead. Just create a mute mp3 and add it as resource.